# Random text view

Tags: text, random, view

I'm having a problem because when I touch my button sometimes my text doesn't appear...

```
function randomText(event)

    display.remove(mmDis)

    local a = { "Cristiano ronaldo jest najlepszy!",
                "messi jest dobry!","lewandowski jest ok", "diego lopez to bramkarz realu"
    }

    com = (a[math.random(1, #a)])

    local mmDis = display.newText(tostring(com), 
        display.contentWidth*0.57, display.contentHeight*0.7,               
        display.contentWidth*0.9, display.contentHeight*0.8, "Impact", 30)
        mmDis.y=20
        mmDis.x=190
        mmDis:setFillColor(0, 0, 0, 1)  
        mmDis.anchorY = 0    
end 

play:addEventListener ("tap", randomText )
```

Comment: "_Sorry for my English!_" (From the [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you. Also, please provide some details on your problem to help others answer your question better.

Comment: Please specify the language both in the question and in the tags.

Comment: what programming language is this?

Comment: after googling a bit, I suspect the language is corona.